# Why did John Goodman say he was sandbagged by being cast as Fred Flintstone?

Tags: casting, always

In the video [John Goodman Breaks Down His Most Iconic Characters | GQ](https://youtu.be/mM_Vo3Zx5u4?t=402) at about `06:42` actor John Goodman says:

> Yeah they kinda sandbagged me. Stephen Spielberg cast me in a film called *Always* and I was just in heaven; this is the best thing.
>
> So on the day of the first table read he said “Ladies and gentlemen, I’d like to say something before we start. I’ve found my Fred Flintstone.” And it just took the wind out of me, it’s not something I was looking forward to doing. Yeah, I felt like I was sandbagged.

**Question:** Why did John Goodman say he was sandbagged? Was he no longer cast in Always?

Comment: @Gnemlock I appreciate the vote change, thank you! I usually don't do it and understand why it's discouraged.

Comment: @Gnemlock It just dawned on my why I probably mistakenly thought JG was saying that he lost the part. Somehow in my head I probably mixed up the terms "sacked" and "sandbagged". Had he said "sacked" (which he didn't) it would have meant that he lost the part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Goodman didn't want to play Fred Flintstone, so Spielberg announcing his casting choice in a somewhat public meeting put him on the spot and made it hard/impossible to refuse:

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sandbagging

> to coerce or intimidate, as by threats

https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/sandbag

> to sandbag someone is to trick or bully them into doing something.
>
> to deceive or coerce someone to get something you want.

Answer (score 5):

John Goodman still starred in *Always*: he played Al Yackey, the best friend of protagonist Pete Sandich. Here he is on the poster:

[image]

*The Flintstones* didn't begin filming until 1993, four years after *Always* was released, so Spielberg could cast him in the former without affecting his participation in the latter.

As for why Goodman felt sandbagged, he may have felt that Spielberg only cast him in *Always* so that he could then try and convince him to play to play Fred Flintstone, a role Goodman might not have initially wanted.

Comment: Okay good for him thanks! So it seems I don't understand why he felt it was a sandbagging then.

Comment: I've adjusted the question a bit in order to try to stave off the down voting; I don't think the change affects the quality of your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @uhoh I've reworded it a bit and moved my earlier comment into the answer, as it addresses the newer version.